# Warning: Attempt to read property "post_status" + "ID " on null in template.php

Tags: php, wordpress, caching

I have used cache plugin to optimize website speed, then start receiving these warnings in customizing page https://i.stack.imgur.com/vY0q3.png
and customize is not working probably (not publishing, it publish only after clearing browser cache)

I have tried :

1. clear cache
2. deleting cache plugin
3. deactivating recently updated plugins
4. reinstalled WordPress version
5. troubleshooting the website using health checker and deactivated all used plugins and themes and installed other one

with no solution

what should I do please?